# Writing data to the firebase realtime database in one activity and reading the data in another

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Premise of App**: CatalogActivity displays list of pets that were entered and stored in the Firebase Realtime Database. It has a floating action button that leads to an EditorActivity that allows users to insert information about a Pet and add it to the list in the CatalogActivity.

**Problem**: I can write the data to the Firebase Realtime database in the EditorActivity, but I'm having trouble reading the data into an adapter in the CatalogActivity. Since I defined and attached my childEventListener in the onCreate of the EditorActivity, when I first open the app, the catalog layout is empty until I click on the floating action button. *How would I make it so that all the data is displayed in the Catalog layout when I first open the app?* I was thinking of instantiating all the firebase variables in the CatalogActivity and then make them static public so that the EditorActivity can use them when necessary. Will that work?

**CatalogActivity**:

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mPetListView;
    public static PetAdapter mPetAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        // Initialize reference to views
        mPetListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        mPetListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        // Initialize pet ListView and its adapter
        List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
        mPetAdapter = new PetAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, pets);
        mPetListView.setAdapter(mPetAdapter);

        // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

**EditorActivity**:

```
public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    // EditText fields to enter the pet's name, breed, weight, and gender
    private EditText mNameEditText;
    private EditText mBreedEditText;
    private EditText mWeightEditText;
    private Spinner mGenderSpinner;

    // Gender of the pet. The possible values are 0 for unknown, 1 for male, and 2 for female
    private int mGender = 0;

    ...

    private Pet mPet;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("pets");

        ...

        // Find all relevant views that we will need to read user input from
        mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_name);
        mBreedEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_breed);
        mWeightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_weight);
        mGenderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);

        // Setup OnTouchListeners on all the input fields, so we can determine if the user
        // has touched or modified them. This will let us know if there are unsaved changes
        // or not, if the user tries to leave the editor without saving.
        mNameEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mBreedEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mWeightEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mGenderSpinner.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);

        setupSpinner();

        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                mPet = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pet.class);
                PetAdapter petAdapter = CatalogActivity.mPetAdapter;
                petAdapter.add(mPet);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply attach the listener you need in the `EditorActivity .onCreate` again?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't quite understand.  Also, you were awesome in Udacity's Firebase in a Weekend course!  You explained everything so well!

Comment: Alex answered pretty much what I commented. :-)  Firebase only keeps the data in sync when there is an active listener. So either you need to keep the listener active between the activities, or you'll need to attach a new listener in the second activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display data from a Firebase database if you do not use a listener, that's why your ListView is empty. So, all you need to do is to add a new listener in your `EditorActivity` to display those items correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Update the mPetAdapter data in "onResume()" method in the CatalogActivity. Or use "Observer pattern" listening the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the firebase instance in CatalogActivity
and implement the **addValueEventListener** of Firebase. the **onDataChange**   listen when new data added/updated

sample code

```
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("abc").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```